# How to change background colour to specific viewholder items in a RecycleView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to change background color in specific item(s) in a RecycleView.
Because I need to set text too, I have the following code that works fine:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(RankingViewHolder viewHolder, final Ranking model, int position) 
{
    final Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    viewHolder.txt_name.setText(model.getUserName());
    viewHolder.txt_score.setText(String.valueOf(model.getScore()));
    viewHolder.txt_class.setText(model.getUser_class());

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(model.getAvatarUrl()).error(R.drawable.ic_people_black_24dp).into(viewHolder.personPhoto);

    int totalRanking = adapter.getItemCount();
    int realRank = totalRanking - viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

    viewHolder.ranknumber.setText("# "+String.valueOf(realRank));
}
```

This works as I want and `realRank`takes the correct values, and the `viewHolder.ranknumber.setText("# "+String.valueOf(realRank));`

Sets the right text with no problem.

Now I am trying (as I got a number/text result correct, to make an if statement like this:

```
if(adapter.getItemCount() -viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == 0)
{
    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}

if(adapter.getItemCount() -viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == 1)
{
    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}

if(adapter.getItemCount() -viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == 2)
{
    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

(I tried with `String.valueOf(realRank)`equality, with `realRank`equality too)
In all cases I have the same result. The color changes as its should at positions 1,2,3 BUT it changes at positions 7,8,9 and 14,15,16  and 21,22,23 etc.

What am I missing here?

```
public class RankingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public TextView txt_name, txt_score, txt_class, ranknumber;

    public ImageView personPhoto;

    public RankingViewHolder(View itemView) 
    {
        super(itemView);
        txt_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        txt_score = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_score);
        personPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        txt_class = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_class);
        ranknumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranknumber);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view , getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }
}
```

The adapter:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ranking, RankingViewHolder>(
                Ranking.class,
                R.layout.layout_ranking,
                RankingViewHolder.class,
                rankingTbl.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(100)
        )
```

This line of code `int realRank = totalRanking - viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();`gives a number (1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.) Why i cannot use this number to check equality?

**Notice**

Keeping this code for NOT working solution, just for future reference:

```
if(position == 0){
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
else if(position == 1){
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
else if(position == 2){
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
else{
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

This changes the color BUT not for only 3 first items. As you scroll down, changes the color for every 3 first viewable items like before, meaning 1,2,3,  7,8,9, etc.

**Update:**

I dont use a custom adapter, i use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.
Thanks to @Muhammad Haroon comment i checked that has getItemViewType. So now i m trying with it like

```
position =adapter.getItemViewType( 0);
                if(position == 0){
                    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
```

Not working for now, but i think its the correct direction...

**Update 2**

With position its not possible as RecycleView recycles the views so i have the same result. The working code is

```
if (linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() > 0) {
                    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackframe);
                }
                else{
                    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goldframe);
                }
```

Works fine except that after scrolling loosing the change of background.

So as we want and need the perfection, any idea for keeping even after scroll?

Comment: add this overriden method  getItemViewType and check if working

Comment: @JinsLukose   add it in viewholder? can you be more specific pls

Comment: yes inside your adapter class. it's a overriden function

Comment: @JinsLukose I dont use a custom adapter. The code is the RankingViewHolder and the adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ranking, RankingViewHolder>(
                Ranking.class,
                R.layout.layout_ranking,
                RankingViewHolder.class,
                rankingTbl.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(100)

Answer (score 2):

hi try add this in your Adapater it may solve your problem.

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It throws android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1a. Trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try

override in your custom adapter

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

and in in your adapter object:

```
myAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```

Comment: I dont use custom adapter. As you can see in adapter code, i use FirebaseRecycleAdapter wich is almost the same with RecycleAdapter. it has alredy getItemId, getViewType. But i dont know how to use it to get ONLY the first item.

Answer (score 0):

In `populateViewHolder` add these line of code

```
if(position == 0){
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
else if(position == 1){
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
else if(position == 2){
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
else{
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

position is a parameter in `populateViewHolder`.

Comment: As i said this is not working. Changes the values to ANY visible item that has position 1,2,3 at the time you scroll. Its a ranking list and i want ONLY the First item "highlighted. I managed it if you check the last update with findFirstVisibleItemPosition(). The only porblem is that it looses the change when you scroll back . Trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: check my notice . As i said whatever has to do with position, changes color for EVERY 3 viewable items. I need to change ONLY FIRST 3 items. So the only working solution is findFirstVisibleItemPosition() and make the countings. Except scrolling back that i m currently working.